# Wordpress private post issue

Tags: php, wordpress, hide, show

i want private posts has been show only to members (Login users)

i edit post as private, so only logged in user users can see these posts but its also not shown to logged in users

i also use this in functions.php

```
$subrole = get_role( 'subscriber' );

// For private pages

$subrole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );

/// For private posts

$subrole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
```

but in vain

please help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this plugin  http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-hide-others-posts/ This plugin creates a new permission, "view_others_posts". When viewing the posts lists in the admin area, users without the "view_other_posts" permission will only see there own posts, not the posts of other users. That plugin will help you to change as you like

otherwise you can try this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ this plugin will help to manage all roles, it is very simple.

Comment: i think u not got my point. i say i want posts private that only "Logged in" users can see not others

Comment: above plugin will help you to change as you like, i have customized aboove plugin. please go with the coding part of that plugin.  otherwise you can try this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ this plugin will help to manage all roles